# How to find out the size of my iOS app? Is it larger than the Cellular Download limit?

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, size

Xcode project says one thing, on my iPhone in the iPhone's setting under usage it gives a different size. I'm confused, don't know which to rely on. How do I find out for sure?

I've read to check the Binary size in App Store Connect. However, I'm not ready for distributing my app yet, I'm still testing so I don't want to dig deep into App Store Connect yet. What are my options?

Comment: Where do you see the 160kB number?

Comment: On the mac desktop when i click on my Xcode Project it pops up and says 160kb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the estimated size (which is going to be close to exact with the App-store size of your app) of your project in 3 easy steps. I added images below.

1-Choose iOS Device as your Target Device.

2-Click Product>Archive.

3-After it compiles with no errors, The Organizer screen will Appear.

4-Click on `Estimate Size` in this screen.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE (June 2015)**

The latest version of Xcode does not have the 'Estimated App Store Size' option within the 'Organizer' view. :(

Instead, Once your app is ready for distribution, archive the app. In the Organizer, select the Archives tab. Select your app in the left hand column. Select the latest archive in the middle column. Hit the Export button in the right hand column. Select `Save for iOS App Store Deployment`. Check file size in the Finder.

Answer (score 4):

## Two methods of getting your app size

1. Export your app from Xcode and get App Thinning Size Report.txt
2. Upload to iTunesConnect and get final estimates

### Export your app from Xcode and get App Thinning Size Report.txt

1. Archive the app
2. Start the export of the app as AdHoc
3. For App Thinning options choose `All compatible device variants`

[image: App Thinning - All compatible device variants]

4. In the output folder open `App Thinning Size Report.txt`

### Upload to AppStore Connect

In the past AppStore Connect was only for AppStore release, but now you can upload your app for TestFlight too.

1. Archive your app
2. Export your app to App Store
3. Go to iTunes Connect
4. My Apps -> Name of Your App -> Activity -> Build Number -> App Store File Sizes

[image: App Store Build Info]

[image: Estimated device sizes]

### Technical Q&A QA1795

[Reducing the size of my App](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/qa/qa1795/_index.html)

This Technical Q&A from Apple states that the iTunes Connect method is The Way to estimate your download size for purposes of Cellular Download Limit.

> The size of your app on the App Store is available in the App File
> Size information provided by iTunes Connect. If you are concerned
> about your app being over the cellular download limit, your build on
> iTunes Connect will indicate if the build is over the cellular
> download limit.

### App Store Connect Help

Documentation for App Store usage from App Store.

[View the file sizes of a build (iOS, tvOS)](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3b56ce97c)

Comment: Today, I found it in My Apps -> Name of Your App -> TestFlight -> Select one of the builds in the list -> Build Metadata -> App Store File Sizes